# Kube-proxy interaction with Kubernetes master api: config-sync-period

Tags: kubernetes, kube-proxy

The kube-proxy gets the Services and Endpoints information from the master api, but how?

According to these links:

http://kubernetes.io/docs/user-guide/services/#proxy-mode-iptables

https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/ee2a0694b649941fc0c3be606746db041b75b91d/cmd/kube-proxy/app/server.go

The proxy seems to be a watcher of the master api, so the update of the proxy information is immediate.

But then, what is the parameter **config-sync-period** ( **How often configuration from the apiserver is refreshed.  Must be greater than 0.** ) in the proxy that defaults to 15 min?

What configuration is refreshed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The sync period is how often we force-refresh the whole state, rather than just doing incremental deltas.  This is a safegauard against potential bugs that might cause syncronized state to drift.

Comment: Is there known bug or certain situation that might cause state to drift?

Comment: No, not known bugs.